# Unit test watch with coverage report on python

Tags: pytest, code-coverage

I develop a package in python. I use pytest and poetry to handle unit test and other package management perks. The code source is available below.

GitHub: https://github.com/trouchet/eule

PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/eule/

You can reproduce the test units with command `make test` or `make test-watch`: the former runs the test once and latter, continuously watches for file changes.

Question: How to generate a test coverage along to `test-watch`?